# Read one field from firestore

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I wanna show the name field of my document in users collection in my firebase firestore using angular

```
let name = this.afs.collection('users').doc('doc_id').get('name');
console.log(name);
```

Comment: Have you looked at https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/firestore/documents.md?

Comment: Please give more details about your collection (structure) and what errors you overcame or are struggling with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fname  = null;
        
this.users = this.afs.collection('users', ref => ref.where("uid", "==", id)).valueChanges();
        
    this.users.subscribe(users => {
       for(let user of users){
          this.fname = user.firstName;
       }
    })
        
console.log(fname);
```